# Difference between Waves MaxxBass and Waves LoAir?

Tags: plug-ins, waves, pro-tools, sub-bass

I could read the manuals but I'm feeling lazy today. Who has used both and can shed light on the strengths and weaknesses of each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've used MaxxBass and RenBass for years and have been using LoAir for about a year.  Here are my observations:

MaxxBass and RenBass have a similar sound.  RenBass has simpler (slimmed down) controls.  While they sound the same, they also can sound different :)  I use them for adding punch, thump, or weight to a sound.  Sometimes MaxxBass works sometimes RenBass, it all depends on the material.

LoAir is completely different.  It is supposed to be like a subharmonic synth (I've never used one).  I use LoAir when I want boom, when I want to shake the house, and when I want my sub bumping.  While I find LoAir is much more of a "wow" effect than the others, I also find that it is easier to make things sound terrible using it.

When I'm designing guns, I rarely use LoAir but often use MaxxBass or RenBass.  LoAir works better for me on things like explosions or big monster footsteps/bodyfalls.  I also tend to use LoAir at more extreme settings than the other 2.

That's my take on it, others may have different experiences.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, LoAir enhance/adds in subharmonic or low end content. MaxxBass adds in harmonic content in the upper registers to help perceive the low end of a track as more present and louder witout overdriving the low end (it's really good for that too).

So MaxxBass=adds/enhances upper registry harmonics for low end sound, LoAir=adds/enhances lower frequency content for higher end/thin sounds.